# How to out-of-range error check this double to string converter with specific decimal precision?

Tags: c#

I am using this routine to convert a double to a string with keeping only two decimal numbers:

```
private string DoubleToString(double num)
{
   string buffer = num.ToString();
   return buffer.Substring(0, buffer.IndexOf(".") + 2);
}
```

However, sometimes the actual value of the parameter `num` is only 1 decimal. How can I error check that?

Comment: Why not `num.ToString("F2")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use double's ToString method with a custom format instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx

`num.ToString("0.00")` will guarantee 2 decimals

More about formats -

Standard - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Custom - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx